# Do I still need XAMP with php version 5.6

Tags: php, xampp

I am returning to php after a long time (although I have a very basic understanding of php in general), and understand that I can run a php server locally by running the command now with version 5.6:

```
php -S localhost:8080
```

Do I still need to install XAMP or WAMP as many of the online tutorials are suggesting or am I okay to just use the above command?

Note: I have postgresql installed on my computer already and do not use mysql, if that matters at all

Comment: Not sure what you are planning to do in PHP, you'll probably run into limitations with the integrated development server. I'd go for a manual install of Apache, PHP and PostgreSQL.

Comment: XAMPP does have MySQL RDBMS included(M in "XAMPP" stands for it), So having a virtual web server & PHP interpreter doesn't suffice. But coz you have postgresql, You dont need mysql (at least for development). But Be aware that 90% of shared web hosting providers offer MySQL & not PostgreSQL, So you'd better use db access abstraction library like "PDO" to help make your apps work without heavy changes while migrating to the production environment.

Answer (score 0):

You need a webserver which you prefer depends on you. XAMPP is the most used for private but you could also take a look at BigApache, EasyPHP, PHPTriad, MampServer, WampServer.

Answer (score 0):

Xampp is a combination of below

1. Apache server
2. Mysql server
3. PHP
   and others.

This is a pretty famous and most used package. But if you want to install everything manually then thats even better you can control your server in any way you want. Go for it and you will learn more about it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a very flexible development environment you need to use a package like EasyPHP Devserver (http://www.easyphp.org/) or equivalent.